# How to apply text over image on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to apply text over image on hover to every picture without it messing up elements  container.

I've tried [THIS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp) and solutions similar, but It doesn't work for me.

This is what I have.

```
/*CSS*/
.item {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.kulso {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.kulso2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```
<!--HTML-->

<div class="kulso">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="./img/long_macchiato.jpg" width="300px" height="200px" />

        <p>Long Macchiato</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="./img/longblack.jpg" width="300px" height="200px" />
        <p>Long Black</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="./img/café latte.jpg" width="300px" height="200px" />
        <p>Café Latte</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="./img/ristretto.jpg" width="300px" height="200px" />
        <p>Ristretto</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="kulso2">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="./img/Cappuccino.jpg" width="300px" height="200px" />
        <p>Capuccino</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="./img/flat-white.jpg" width="300px" height="200px" />
        <p>Flat White</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="./img/mocha-coffee.jpg" width="300px" height="200px" />
        <p>Mocha Coffee</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="./img/affogato.jpg" width="300px" height="200px" />
        <p>Affogato</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Demo site:
https://peaceful-carson-9d2ad7.netlify.com/products.html/

I understad I have to have a wrapper around each image and caption. My problem is, no matter what properties I'm modifying or adding while trying to apply the text over image on hover using [THIS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp), either...

- "inline-block" is off, the pictures won't stay next to each other
- opacity, transition affects padding between pictures
- the text is in the center of the page, not the picture
- the size of the pictures change

I noticed that adding 
`<div class="text">This is the text that appears on hover in the center of the image</div>`
instantly messes up everything.

*Please give me tips or solutions using my code I shared above!*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div id='hover2change' style="background-image:url('a.png');width:50px;height:50px;">
  <img src="b.png" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:50px;">
</div>

<style>
    #hover2change:hover img {left:-100%;}
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a wrapper around each image and caption, much like the examples you link to. You can modify this a bit as the css could be a bit cleaner but this is the basic thing you can do.

```css
.container {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.container__row {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/* For medium devices (e.g. tablets) */

@media (min-width: 420px) {
  .image-container {
    max-width: 48%;
  }
}


/* For large devices (e.g. desktops) */

@media (min-width: 760px) {
  .image-container {
    max-width: 24%;
  }
}

.egykispadding {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.image-container__caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 140ms;
}

.image-container:hover .image-container__caption {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__row egykispadding">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2c8c.png" width="400" height="200" />
      <div class="image-container__caption">Image caption</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container__row">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2c8c.png" width="400" height="200" />
      <div class="image-container__caption">Image caption</div>
    </div>

    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2c8c.png" width="400" height="200" />
      <div class="image-container__caption">Image caption</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, but It still messes up the container elements.

Comment: @Akuhei in what way does it mess them up? If we know we could instruct you how to change so it works. Please update your question with that information.